# What and where is the max?

Tags: code-golf, array

This small challenge derives from my annoyance at discovering that numpy doesn't have a built in function for it.

## Input

An n by m matrix of integers.

## Output

The maximum value in the matrix and the 2d coordinates of one of its occurrences.  The coordinates should be in the order (row_idx, col_idx) if your code is no shorter than it would be with (col_idx, row_idx). Otherwise it can be (col_idx, row_idx) but if so, please explain it in your answer.

1-based indexing is allowed too

## Examples

```
Input [[1, 2], [3, 4]]. Output (4, (1, 1))
Input [[-1]]. Output (-1, (0, 0))
Input [[6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [1]]. Output (6, (0, 0))
Input [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 5, 3], [-5, -2, 3, 5]]. Output (5, (1, 2))
```

## Note

[numpy](https://numpy.org/) answers gratefully received too.

Comment: May we return the coordinates of all occurrences?

Comment: @chunes Just one please.

Comment: I don't think "The coordinates should be in the order (row_idx, col_idx)" adds anything.

Comment: @JonathanAllan It just mimics the problem I was trying to solve in numpy.

Comment: Yes, but it adds nothing to the challenge, I suggest removing it (much like one would generally allow both zero and one indexing).

Comment: @JonathanAllan I succumbed to peer pressure.

Answer (score 10):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 7 bytes

```julia
findmax
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/Py0zLyU3seK/Q3FGfrkClKcRbahgpGCsYGKtYABkmCoYWyvomirogsRMYzX/AwA)

Outputs `(value, CartesianIndex(row_index, col_index))` (1-indexed)

Comment: A genuine built-in answer!

Answer (score 9):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/) + [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html), 48 bytes

```python
lambda x:(x.max(),divmod(x.argmax(),x.shape[1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU9BDoIwELzzij22SSGgYAwJL6k91ABCYktTiilv8UJi9Ac-xt_YFvGyuzM7s5m9v9RsukEuj7Y6PSfTxsdPeuXiXHOwJbKJ4BZhUvc3MdQOcn1ZGZuMHVcNzRjGP9-7F2rQBuQk1Ax8BKki04xmhApoBEBpRmDHCNA9gZwxErg426aDXxW-5EHkS5D_Fd5PILgdnQZUOMKj2A3xui0Yi1jUDhoM9BJChtIdULqXBrVIKveH5jMyeAu_LGv_Ag)

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: `x.shape[1]` is `len(x.T)`

Comment: @ovs I knew there was a `len` trick but I didn't think of transpose

Answer (score 6):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 9 bytes

```
⊢⊚⊃=∘/↥♭.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4oqi4oqa4oqDPeKImC_ihqXima0uCgpmIFtbMSAyXVszIDRdXQpmIFtbwq8xXV0KZiBbWzZdIFs1XSBbNF0gWzNdIFsyXSBbMV1dCmYgW1sxIDIgMyA0XSBbMCAyIDUgM10gW8KvNSDCrzIgMyA1XV0K)

```
⊢⊚⊃=∘/↥♭.
        .  # duplicate
       ♭   # deshape
     /↥    # maximum
  ⊃=∘      # mask of where the max exists in input
 ⊚         # coordinates of the ones
⊢          # first
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 3 bytes

```
Þė↑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLDnsSX4oaRIiwiIiwiW1sxLCAyLCAzLCA0XSwgWzAsIDIsIDUsIDNdLCBbLTUsIC0yLCAzLCA1XV0iXQ==)

And they said maximum by tail was useless! Now who's laughing! (me... It's me who's laughing)

Outputs `[[x, y], item]`.

### Explained

```
Þė↑­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Þė   # ‎⁡Multidimensional enumeration
  ↑  # ‎⁢Maximum by tail
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: I don't think you need to reverse the list anymore, the challenge was reworded

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

−1 byte thanks to Mukundan314

Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems. Returns `[max, row_idx, col_idx]`

```apl
M,⍴⊤,⍳M←⌈/,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/311HvVuedS1BEht9gWKPOrp0Nf5nwZi9fY96mp@1LsGqODQeuNHbROBuoKDnIFkiIdnMEgNSMQr2N9PPTraUEfBKFZHIdpYR8EkNladC1VW1xBTzAyk3BREmIA1ggiwEVjUgkzXUQCbDVRgAOaZAgVAPF0gQxciawrUCQA)

`⌈/` the maximum (lit. maximum reduction) of the

`,` ravelled (flattened) argument

`M←` store that as `M` (for **M**aximum)

`,⍳` **i**ndex of first location of that in the ravelled (flattened) argument

`⍴⊤` the shape-radix representation of that

`M,` prepend the Maximum

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/311HvVuedS1BEht9gWKPOrp0Nf5nwZi9fY96mp@1LsGqODQeuNHbROBuoKDnIFkiIdnMEgNSMQr2N9PPTraUEfBKFZHIdpYR8EkNladC1VW1xBTzAyk3BREmIA1ggiwEVjUgkzXUQCbDVRgAOaZAgVAPF0gQxciawrUCQA)

Comment: @Mukundan314 thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
(*+&=)\||//\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwlirsNwCAQxXqmeFUEySHC51LkKZtQMwXD5xCVLcvj9ed1fKHPmVJ3bsBnFFa0sFwk5i0PRSmNlVIoO9oJO3kbFZVREVfRgB8eEBDs)

```
        |//           max
           \    (mat,    )
(    )\|        (max,        )
   &=                 indices
 *+                   first
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

Returns `[max, y, x]`.

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>m=v<m[0]?m:[v,y,x]))&&m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BDoMgEETv/QpOBpLFaCs9NMV@COFArDZtXDHYEP16CnhrvEz27c7sfIw3S@fe85dP9tmHQQaULZZoZkodbEy2bgcPawSU/o6q0g@8KQ8brJqxosDQ2WmxY1@O9kUHqlQN5KyBqAuQRkfP6d/A68P1NYVEkibHk@RHx/ZUAySXRE@VScRFIh4Hvl9FCocf)

Comment: Is `[ 5, [ 3, 2 ] ]` correct in your TIO? I think it should be `[ 5, [ 2, 3 ] ]`

Comment: @Simd [Do you really need a strict output format?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/58563)

Comment: The output  format isn't strict, but the order of the coordinates is. I hope that's ok. For example, the Vyxal output is fine.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒĖṚ€Ṁ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a (multidimensional) array and yields a pair, `[maximum-value, [row, column, ...]]` using 1-indexing. (Identifying the last location of the maximum-value.)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opCPTHu6c9ahpzcOdDf///4@OVjDUUVAwAmJjIDaJ1eFSiFYwADJNodgYLKQLZOrCVJkChWIB)**

#### How?

While Jelly has both `ŒM` (get *all* multidimensional indices of maximal elements), `œị` (get element at multidimensional index y), and `œi` (get first multidimensional index of y), amongst some others I think this may be the tersest approach...

```
ŒĖṚ€Ṁ - Link: multidimensional array of comparables, A
ŒĖ    - multidimensional enumerate
  Ṛ€  - reverse each (from [coordinates, value] to [value, coordinates])
    Ṁ - maximum
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) + numpy, 61 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(zip(x.flat,ndindex(x.shape)))
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU5BDoIwELzzij0WU4woGEPCS7CHGmhoQktTlgT8igdJjP7J39gW9bK7MzszmdvLzNj2enmI8vwcUSSnd9lxdak5TIXiE7lKQ6at6DhSXUtdN5ODQ8tNE8dxJGyvQI_KzCCV6S1uviF3bAYcoIQqAqiqlMKeUagOFDLGaOCS9Hcd_Sv3IwsiP4L8r_B-CsHt6F1AuSM8StyRrN-csYhForeAIDWEDoULMFZqJIJwa_lM0DVfay7Luj8)

Returns the last index of the maximal value. Different 63 bytes, maybe `key=` can shorten this a bit?

```python
lambda x:max((b,a)for a,b in ndenumerate(x))
from numpy import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU7dCoIwFL73Kc7lFhOyNEKQHmTtYuJGQpsyj6DP0kVC1Dv1Nm2zujk_3x_f7dXPeOns8tDV-TmiTo_v01WaupEwlUZOhNRMUt05kKyG1oJtlB2NchIVmShNtOsMeKSfoTV953DzjbmjGnCACngCwHnGYCcY8D2DXAgWsTT7XYdAFWHkURRGlP8Vwc8guj28jV_hgfCl_khXthAiEUnoi6Ft7FD6gN61Fokm0jk5E6SUrjWXZd0f)

Comment: It's very likely the shortest numpy will avoid the import by only calling methods of the array argument

Comment: If only I had known about ndenumerate! I like these solutions a lot.

Comment: @Simd If you're looking for a proper solution, I'd probably do `argmax` + `unravel_index`.

Comment: [Yes, no imports!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269848/96480)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
{s=Max@#,#&@@#~Position~s-1}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277v7rY1jexwkFZR1nNwUG5LiC/OLMkMz@vrljXsFbtf0BRZl6JgkO6Q3W1oY6CkY6CsY6CSa2OQrUBmGcKFADxdIEMXYisaW3t//8A)

-1 byte from @att

Comment: `FirstPosition` -> `#&@@ Position`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 35 bytes

Almost built-in, but `which.max` flattens the input.

```r
\(x,m=max(x))c(m,which(x==m,T)[1,])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3lWM0KnRybXMTKzQqNDWTNXJ1yjMykzM0Kmxtc3VCNKMNdWI1oUo70jRyE0uKMis0kjUMdYx0jHVMNHXyivLLbY10kipBdIimJhdcka4hMs_MylBHAazYDJtiuIk6BkDaFMjSNdXRBYmYQu0wRmiDuGfBAggNAA)

Fixed indexing and returned result, thanks to Giuseppe.

Comment: I think you are supposed to return exactly one of the coordinates; this will return all of them.

Comment: @Giuseppe I see; the behavior is different than `which.max`.

Comment: You can shrink this by using match instead of which because that will automatically only return the first match. So \(x,m=max(x))c(m,match(m,x)) should do the job.

Comment: @quarague I think `match` will return 1-dimensional index, not 2.

Comment: I think you can index and return the first row only -- in fact, as it stands now, this isn't correct since this'll return the first two entries, columnwise! so `which(x==m,T)[1,]`.

Comment: @Giuseppe thank you. Interestingly for the third test case, the first row and first column are the same.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>12</s> 8 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize)*

```
{iiʰ}ᶠot
```

Outputs as `[[max, col], row]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vzoz89SG2ofbFuSX/P8fHW2oo2Cko2Cso2ASq6MQbQDmmQIFQLx4ICMeImsaG/s/AgA)

**Explanation**

```
{iiʰ}ᶠot
{   }ᶠ    Find all ways of satisfying this predicate:
 i         Get some [element, index] pair (i.e. a row and its row index)
  iʰ       Apply the same operation to that row, turning it into an element and
           its column index
          We now have a list of [[element, col], row] for each element in the array
      o   Sort ascending
       t  Take the last one
```

### Nicer output format, 11 bytes

```
{iiʰ}ᶠotgᵗc
```

Outputs as `[max, col, row]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P/lRT6evWmbmqQ3pD7dOT9bL8H3Usfz//@hoQx0FIx0FYx0Fk1gdhWgDMM8UKADixQMZ8RBZ09jY/xEA)

**Explanation**

```
{iiʰ}ᶠotgᵗc
{iiʰ}ᶠot     Same as above, gives [[max, col], row]
        gᵗ   Wrap the last element in a singleton list: [[max, col], [row]]
          c  Concatenate: [max, col, row]
```

To output as `[max, row, col]` is **12 bytes**; the only change is to transpose the matrix first with `\`:

```
\{iiʰ}ᶠotgᵗc
```

To output as `[max, [row, col]]` as originally requested is... longer. Brachylog doesn't handle mixed-type lists very well.

Comment: I think [`{iiʰ}ᶠot`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vzoz89SG2ofbFuSX/P8fHW2oo2Cko2Cso2ASq6MQbQDmmQIFQLx4ICMeImsaG/s/AgA) works (8 bytes and same output format). Outside of golfing, your answer is better though because it can list all maximums, whereas this one only gives the last one.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Since `⌉` doesn't work on nested lists, I assumed incorrectly that `o` wouldn't either.

Answer (score 4):

## Rust + ndarray, 41 bytes

```rust
|a|a.indexed_iter().max_by_key(|(_,x)|*x)
```

A closure of type `fn(&Array2<u8>)->Option<((usize, usize), &u8)>`.

`ndarray_stats` has an `argmax`, but it's very verbose at 46 bytes:

```rust
{use ndarray_stats::*;|a|(a.max(),a.argmax())}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>56</s> 55 bytes

*Another one bytes the dust thanks to [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766).*

```hs
f m=maximum[(c,(y,x))|(y,r)<-e m,(x,c)<-e r]
e=zip[0..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5BDoMwDLvzCh9bKUWwwU7jCXtBlUOFilaNIgRMYtP@3rXdTuTgxI4d5W7Whx3HEAb4zpvd@afXoifxol3KT2yLvCoLT2KnPo8LF7Z7u1lXZclhs@u2ooOG1jXhxAR9JjTMBf4VFa3qg3BJxjZBkyMJcvhoTEcJ@WSkVWZtFBJTcVC/bcsMLgpv3BS/8Wa@QcyLmzaUGCTym@EL)

Heh, this is technically a built-in solution. Outputs as `(max, (y, x))`.

### Weird output solution, <s>46</s> 39 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to to [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766).*

```hs
maximum.e.map(maximum.e)
e=(`zip`[0..])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5BCsIwELznFXNsIQmttt76BF8QFxpKqsFGgqkgPt6YRPHQPQw7szvDXHS4mmWJ83CKTj@tezhppNO@@rOamaEaX9aPqpGS6riasAYMUFCq5dgRh9pzdEQMv0mKEu1GOOTHPkNXLBmKefuYQzlKZKJNYX0SMhNpEd9rTwRizGl7S21S5yMqf7e3FRJzjVIzvqd50ecQxeT9Bw)

This effectively does the same thing but outputs as `((max, x), y)`.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##XU5BDoMwDLv3FT62Uopgg53GE/aCKocKgVaNTgiYxND@3rXdTuTgxI4d5W6XRz@OIQzwrbeb8y9vZEfyTZtSn9hmddU7PMmNujzOLPZ2d5Mpi4LD2i/rghYGxlSEExPMmVAzC/wrKkZXB@GSjE2COkcS5PDRmI4S8slIy8yaKCSm46B/24YZLIS37hm/8Xa6QU6ze64oMCjkN8MX) for the first one, [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##XU5BCoMwELznFXNUSIK22ptP6AvSBYNoG2okNBaKj2@apKUH9zDszO4Mc9P@Ps5zmLpLsPpl7NPKTVrtij8r2dYV/WZcryopqQzr6FePDgpK1RwH4lBHjoaI4TdRUaLeCaf02CZosiVBNu8fUyhHjoy0yqyNQmIiLuJ7bYlAjFltltgmdj6jcA@zrJCYSuSa4T1Ms776IAbnPg) for the second one

Comment: @DLosc But... But the elegance of a one-liner! :P Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
˜Z=kIнg‰,
```

0-based; outputs the maximum and coordinate on separated newlines.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//9Jwo22zPC3vTHzVs0Pn/PzraUMdIx1jHJFYn2gDIMtUxBrJ0TXV0QaKmsbEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLkFQO5OpX/T8@Jss2uvLA3/VHDBp3/h7bZ/4@OjjbUMYrViTbWMYmN1VGIjtY1hNBmQEFTIDYBSQIxSBFUCqhDB6ReJ9oAyDLVAUnrmurogkRNY2NjAQ).

**Explanation:**

Unfortunately, 05AB1E lacks multidimensional builtins, so things are done manually. Otherwise this could have been 4-5 bytes probably.

```python
˜          # Flatten the (implicit) input-matrix
 Z         # Push its maximum (without popping the list)
  =        # Print this max with trailing newline (without popping again)
   k       # Pop both now, and get the 0-based index of this max in the list
    Iнg    # Push the width of the input-matrix (push input; first item; length)
       ‰   # Divmod the index by this width
        ,  # Pop and print it with trailing newline as well
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `MList::Util=max -p` 58 bytes

```perl
$\=max/-?\d+/g;/\[[^[]*$\\b/;say$`=~y/[//-1;say$&=~y/,//}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lxjY3sUJf1z4mRVs/3Vo/Jjo6LjpWSyUmJknfujixUiXBtq5SP1pfX9cQzFUDcXX09Wur//@PjjbUUTCK1VGINtZRMImN/ZdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0ABI@2QWl1hZhZZk5oCs@a9bAAA)

Output format is

```perl
row
column
max
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈ＥＡ⟦⌈ικ⌕ι⌈ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexIjO3NBdIF2h45hWUlmho6ihEw0QzgZxsHQW3zLwUjUwdBYRwrCYQWP//Hx0dbaijYKSjYKyjYBIL1GkA5pkCBUA8XSBDFyJrGhsb@1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the highest possible row with the maximum value but the lowest possible column in that row. Explanation:

```
   Ａ            Input array
  Ｅ             Map over rows
      ι         Current row
     ⌈          Maximum value
       κ        Current index
        ⌕       First index of
           ι    Current row
          ⌈     Maximum value
         ι      In current row
    ⟦           Make into list
 ⌈              Take the maximum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Getting the maximum column of the maximum row can be done for 14 bytes:

```
Ｉ⌈ＥＡ⟦⌈ικ⌈⌕Ａι⌈ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexIjO3NBdIF2h45hWUlmho6ihEw0QzgZxsHQUY1y0zL8UxJ0cjEyGUqakZqwkE1v//R0dHG@ooGOkoGOsomMQCTTEA80yBAiCeLpChC5E1jY2N/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｉ⌈ＥＡ⟦⌈ικ        As above
         ⌕Ａ     Find all indices of
             ι  Current row
            ⌈   Maximum value
           ι    In current row
        ⌈       Take the maximum
```

Getting the lowest possible row with the lowest possible column takes a massive 21 bytes:

```
ＩＥ⌈Ｅθ⟦⌈ι±κ⌕ι⌈ι⟧⎇⊖κι±ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCgIxDIRfpccupODfnjwq3hQP3koPoRs0uO1qraJPX7MVNRCYbyZD/AmTH7AvZZ84Zr3CW9ZbvMg@OdxD1VdQ9svcgNrRETPps8gNx04zqH/sxD1Qipheek0@UaCYqavX/OtyM86yFGvtFNQM1BzUwsmjSaVWjJGMCPNJW@dcMY/@DQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Negates the row number, which gives you the highest possible negated row, but then has to negate it again for display.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, <strike>63</strike> 59 bytes

```
=+sort(tocol(A:N&","&row(A:N)&","&column(A:N)),tocol(A:N),)
```

Put the 2D array in cells `A1:N1000` and the formula in cell `P1`.

Singularizes the data and coordinates and sorts in descending order. Uses unary plus `+` to extract just the first result. Gives 1-indexed coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 147 bytes

```go
import."slices"
func f(I[][]int)(m,x,y int){m=Max(I[0])
for _,r:=range I{m=max(m,Max(r))}
for a,r:=range I{x,y=a,Index(r,m)
if y>-1{break}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVHBSgMxEMVrvmJcEHZhtrTaiigRBD30oIj2VovEdVcWu2nJprJLzFd49FIEf8Lf8KRf4yRpsYIQkpd5b95MJq9vD7Plx1xkj-Ihh0qUkrGyms-U7kRFpaP3hS7Sg6-XdayellleR6xYyAyKeDiejCel1ElcYYMtOGgqfi4aorqThBUzBbeoDrkSkgoMiayIrNBJVJJYrxCbCvLhAofyPicFVgkrC2iP0565U7l4tJapXC-UtKG1761P3c5zGEGt1SLTYEo5h1VbRzCdZQgNgm_NMvYkFOi81jVwEo0MMyupMT2EXYtg9hD6lkAfgUI9ixuatOeYlOJdWn-ofZc7cFvfu7jN-_mU_X8yXEEEX45kXX8bUMDdUgJpYAcuf-CbIT9Gj_DDd38VJ2AYu1RkN5VxxDm_Hp1cjeiM1qPXcMghjDa827DfmRBVxLpDE_NTJgK2OeiOA8_P0IRb43AbcAsGfL0ijnaegB_Dzj36BfEaJTcyQvC2-PsBGHzd0bitTcDSYzabP7s4Da2v_na5DOcP)

Returns as `max, x, y`. Assumes that the matrix is non-empty.

#### Explanation

```go
import."slices"
func f(I[][]int)(m,x,y int){
 m=Max(I[0])                       // default value for max, to account for negatives
 for _,r:=range I{m=max(m,Max(r))} // find the max of the whole matrix
 for a,r:=range I{                 // find the location of the max
  x,y=a,Index(r,m)                 // the current row index, and the index of the max
  if y>-1{break}}                  // if the max is in this row, exit the loop
 return
}
```

Comment: Go makes it hard!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>66</s> 60 bytes

Vanilla Python approach, outgolfed by the `numpy` versions.

*-6 bytes as lambda expression instead of a function*

```python
lambda m:(a:=max(l:=sum(m,[])),divmod(l.index(a),len(m[0])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5LCoMwFFzrKd7yBZ5FqxYJeJI0i7RRGkiiqC329DZJ280wX5j5vT0mX3fzcoz99bDK3bQCx1Hx3qkdLe/Xp0NHQjJG2rzcpNGejNfDjoqRHTw6UYaQHeO0wF2tAxgPIs@EqAjOkkDUBI2UFK2i@pFLDNoITapESOV/IY4J0jS4ZVJtMKIqAim@aStlnkmeZ/Ni/IYjxgfhzAc)

Comment: Darn, 60 again: `lambda m:(a:=max(r:=max(m,key=max)),(m.index(r),r.index(a)))`

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 11 bytes

```
ᵉ#Ť#ᵒÐᶻᶻÐjṀ
```

[Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6Fjsebu1UPrpE-eHWSYcnPNy2G4gOT8h6uLNhSXFScjFU0YKbOtHRhjoKRjoKxjoKJrE6CtEGYJ4pUADE0wUydCGyprGxEE0A)

This language is cool, though this isn't really using the cooler aspects of it. I also have a sneaking suspicion this can get better.

### Alternate solution, 11 bytes

```
ᵐ{xᶻ,Ṁ}xᶻ,Ṁ
```

[Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6Flsfbp1QXfFw226dhzsbamGMJcVJycVQFQtu6kRHG-ooGOkoGOsomMTqKEQbgHmmQAEQTxfI0IXImsbGQjQBAA)

This is more elegant, but it flips the indices.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 109 chars

```
r←f w;i;j;s;h;k;a;b
j←1⋄s←¯∞⋄h←k←⍬⋄(a b)←⍴w
i←1
→4×⍳∼w[i;j]>s⋄h←i⋄k←j⋄s←w[i;j]
→3×⍳a≥i+←1⋄→2×⍳b≥j+←1
r←s(h,k)
```

19+23+3+30+21+8+5=109

How to use&test:

```
      ⎕fmt f 2 3⍴ 1 4 3 2 ¯1 5
┌2───────┐
│  ┌2───┐│
│5 │ 2 3││
│~ └~───┘2
└∊───────┘
      ⎕fmt 2 3⍴ 1 4 3 2 ¯1 5
┌3──────┐
2 1  4 3│
│ 2 ¯1 5│
└~──────┘
```

it would return the max and the first coordinates it finds max

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 22 bytes

```
xB cr<Asx<<(mM eu<+eu)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5LDoIwFNz3FG8JsU1EwRhSTHTnwoR90wWRNhIBEdqEu7BhY7yCV-E2toXootOZN-8zw_uWdXdRluOUFFXzaBU8dVYWshA5pK0odS7QYqRIxjFj51pxTg6eZwg2z3fw0kqS_Ucm_QmuLT12PaVedQGh6UroxZ4GJTrVQYIAGDAWYNhwDGyLIeTcFA1nJPjRnTUjC6Frs-AG_i12BQa3wMi1U5EpWEUMIbMbuQGOUJUVtbtvsnlNCxSkDy7VHHEc5_8L)

Outputs as `((x,y),v)`

## Strange order, 21 bytes

```
xB(cr<cr)<(mM eu<+eu)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU49DoIwGN17im8ssU1EwRgCDm4OJuxNB4JtJAJiaRPvwsJiPIJn4Ta2hejQ1_e-9_284X0t-puo63HKqqa7Kw0PU9SVrMQFciVqcxFoMXIkk4SxU6s5pweMLSH2BR5eRku6_8jsecSlSksVpLg5gzDpSpjFnQYtet1DhgAYMBYS2HACbEsg4twWLWc0_NGdM2MHkW9z4Af-LW4FAb_AyrVXsS04RS2hsxv7AY5QU1Stv2-z4U5BCjIAn2qOOI7z_wU)

Outputs as `(x,(y,v))`

## Different strange order, 21 bytes

```
mx<g<m(mx<g)
```

```
g=fzp nn
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5LDoIwEN33FLOEpE1EwRgE9y5M2DddkNAisa0IJTFehQ0b4xE8C7exLUYX8-a9efMbX-eyv3AppzlvVHvtDNyGUjai4RUUHZdDxdHXKJBIU0qP2jBGDkFgCbYRengORpDdW-TqntWZClwK93UuHi1ovbjzaHhvesgRAAVKIwxrhoFuMMSM2aLllEQ_unVm4iD2bQ78wL_FrcDgF1i58iqxBaeIJWRxEz_AEFJlo_19dYKg7SADEYL_anlxmpb8AQ)

Outputs as `((v,y),x)`

## Reflection

This answer is hampered by the fact I haven't yet implemented any array handling functions, so this has to work with lists.

That asside, I have a couple of thoughts:

- There should be a flipped version of `eu`. I approximate this with `fzp nn` in the final version.
- `cr<cr` is a useful enough function to have a short version.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 32 bytes

Prompts for matrix:

```
(⌈/,m),(,(⍳↑⍴m)∘.,⍳1↓⍴m)[↑⍒,m←⎕]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv8ajng59nVxNHQ0djUe9mx@1TXzUuyVX81HHDD0dIN/wUdtksEA0WGaSTi5QK9CI2P9A3Vz/07iMFIyA8oYKRgrGCiZcaVyGCoZA/qH1hmC2GZBtpmCqYAKUNVIAiQFVIdQrGABpUyDr0HpTIAaJmXJxAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), <s>114</s> 112 bytes

Output in the format `(value row_idx col_idx)`

```
(λ(x[y(apply append x)][m(flatten y)][i(index-of y m)][l(length(car x))])(list m(quotient i l)(remainder i l)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoIwEEX3nOInLpwumohSL0NYNFCwsRSsNSln8w5eCaeERBd/Mv/N/5mg27uJ68FpPyBspqDO9NYb9Ct93pTqhfQ8uwU8je@QRFOPOxp1wsLekvWdSXLqwZCBI2f8EG/U6sAN0Qhy9hkx0uM1RWt8hIUTFMyoczVsVohVFAX1OBKVOAvQBRXTHcnyt1/5qFhVDrFy@O/MbeQu6MSbQo5IBZmpyn@@)

```scheme
(λ(x
   [y (flatten x)]                      ; flatten the matrix
   [m (apply max y)]                    ; find the max value
   [i (index-of y m)]                   ; index of the value
   [l (length (car x))])                ; length of a row
 (list m(quotient i l)(remainder i l))) ; format output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
->a{b=a.flatten
[m=b.max,b.index(m).divmod(a[0].size)]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3zXXtEquTbBP10nISS0pS87iic22T9HITK3SS9DLzUlIrNHI19VIyy3LzUzQSow1i9Yozq1I1Y2uh2g0LFNyio6MNdRSMdBSMdRRMYnUUog3APFOgAIinC2ToQmRNY2NjIRoXLIDQAA)